# Bash shell parameter in bracket

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that takes arguments for variables as the following:

```
V1=$1; V2=$2; V3=${3:-""};
```

Can someone help explain the syntax used for V3?

Comment: Default value for `$3`. Check `man bash`

Comment: Check the Bash Parameter Expansion section in GNU Bash Manual here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html or this post on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts